# How to sort nsmutable array which containing dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have one array and in that having data like this.

```
(
    {
        avatar = "306_20160701_112934.jpg";
        email = "hardik@gmail.com";
        "full_name" = "hardik ";
        number = 977743;
        "user_id" = 306;
    },
    { 
        avatar = "profileImage_1466836096488.jpg";
        email = "robo@gmail.com";
        "full_name" = "Robot Codol";
        number = 903360;
        "user_id" = 324;
    },
    {
        avatar = "386_20160705_120501.jpg";
        email = "ravi@gmail.com";
        "full_name" = "apu ";
        number = 46576246876;
        "user_id" = 386;
     },
     {
        avatar = "profileImage_1467293381491.jpg";
        email = "testnew@gmail.com";
        "full_name" = "Robot Codol";
        number = 905660;
        "user_id" = 402;
     },
     {
        avatar = "474_20160704_073537.jpg";
        email = "demo@flikit.com";
        "full_name" = "hardik ";
        number = "+9777743";
        "user_id" = 474;
     }
)
```

Now I Want to sort this details in accending order by "full_name" Can you please help in this.

I have tried this code but cant do it.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"full_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
[arrSeggestedContact sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Help in this thank you.

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: it's not giving me a proper sorted array

Comment: what you are getting?

Comment: 'Robot Codol','Robot Codol','apu','hardik','hardik' it's give me sorted array in this way

Comment: and this is not in sorted form as i want

Comment: Hey @Anbu.Karthik you solution works i just have to change one thing that you have mention localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
      initWithKey:@"full_name"
      ascending:YES
      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; // or try with `caseInsensitiveCompare`
```

Comment: welcome bro,  some time `NSSortDescriptor`  facing the case senstive probelm

Answer (score 2):

```
NSSortDescriptor *fullNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"full_name"
  ascending:YES
  selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

NSLog(@"By Full name: %@", [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[fullNameSortDescriptor]]);
```